# Digging near a retaining wall

Tags: shed, retaining-wall

I'm thinking of ideas for building a shed on the side of my house, and a good spot in my opinion would be to have it on the side of my house. My property is a thin long lot so my front yard is all paved and is my driveway, then the rest of the lot is a slight slope all the way to the end of the yard. The side of my house has a few steps to go from the elevation of the driveway, to about 4 ft down. The driveway ends with a 1 ft retaining wall and about 3 ft of dirt that make an angled flower bed (approx 30-35 degree angle).

I'd like to dig out some of that dirt and possibly put the back wall of the shed flush against the retaining wall. I figure I would need to rebuild the retaining wall as I'm sure it doesn't extend much lower than it currently is, but would I be able to use the wall of a shed as my retaining wall? Is this allowed/would I need some extra bracing inside the shed? What are my options for this? Easiest choice would be to build the shed in a different place, but I like this place the best.

[image: View of stairs next to house w/ flower bed next to it.]

Comment: Step 1) Check with your local building commission. Do they have any permits/drawings on record for the building of this retaining wall? Will you require a permit for modifying the wall and/or adding the shed?

Comment: What are you calling a retaining wall?  The concrete step skirt, or the timber wall?

Comment: The picture cuts off where you want this shed, I think. Most people would fill with additional base material to get a level site. Is there some physical constraint against this alternative that would leave your retaining wall untouched?

Comment: @FreeMan, the IRC declares 4 ft retaining walls and below as a free for all unless there are surplus loads on the soil behind the wall, where you could argue whether or not cars on a driveway qualify. It should probably be terraced at 2 ft heights to avoid the ire of building officials, but he's likely fine on his own. LIKELY, not certainly.

Comment: The back of the shed is against that wood retaining wall running along the driveway, right? The soil at the base of that wall is where you want to cut, right?